# Using transform scale on table without borders creates space between <td> elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm using transform scale on hover on my table. This is before I hover (and scale the table)
[image]

This is after the hover (and after it scales)
[image]

You see it somehow creates space between `<td>` elements, and whatever else. 
I've tried a lot of things, like `border-collapse` but I just can't remove it.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="kartica">
    <table class="custom-table table table-hover table-responsive">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    something
                </td>

                <td class="text-center ">
                    something
                </td>

                <td class="text-center">
                    something
                </td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.custom-table {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: none;
}

.custom-table td{
    border: none;
}

.custom-table tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #edf0f3;
}

.kartica:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    -o-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);

    -webkit-transition: all 70ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 70ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 70ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 70ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Is there a way to remove it?

Edit: Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPKjrp).
You should see the thin white lines when you hover over the table.

Comment: Instead of `border: none;` use `border-color: transparent;`

Comment: @AlonEitan I replaced both of the `border: none` with what you said but it did not help

Comment: Show your code on JSFiddle/Codepen or something like this, because the problem doesn't exist in code you presented.

Comment: @m_bale Sorry, misread your question. As the above comment suggest, please demonstrate this issue - You can [edit] your question and you'll see a `<>` button that allow you to create a stack snippet

Comment: @makshh Okay I've added the codepen code

Comment: And where is that border?

Comment: @makshh http://prntscr.com/f7sh69 here if you can't see it (the yellow line on the left of "Helen"), in this case I zoomed in, but like I said on my project it is a lot more visible

Comment: Safari browser? I can only see this on Safari, Firefox and Chrome is ok.

Comment: @makshh This is on chrome xD And the second picture from my question, when it's the most obvious is also chrome

Comment: Strange, try this: `transform: scale(1.05) translateZ(0);`

Comment: @makshh still the same issue :/

Comment: Maybe `.wrap { will-change: transform; }` will help.

Comment: @makshh Doesn't help :/ And it's so unpredictably when it will be visible or not

Comment: @makshh I edited the codepen in the question, now you should clearly see the white lines in chrome?

Comment: zemljak... in the codepen-demonstration I can't see any lines when hovering over the table - using chrome on mac. pozdrav ;-)

Comment: @ad_on_is Pozdrav :D I updated my chrome and I still see the lines! (http://prntscr.com/f7za7h) My chrome version is 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit), may I know yours?

Comment: @makshh I tried using `will-change: transform` again and it now somehow works! (on the codepen example) The problem is that now the text is definitely blurry. I think I'm going crazy, but I'll now try it on my project again since it didn't seem to work before.

Comment: It works on the codepen but not on my project.. Ah I'll just give up and cheat with adding left and right borders on `<tr>` hover in the color of the weird "lines"

Comment: my version is the same as yours: Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit). did you try  it with chrome's private mode, or some other browser? maybe you have some kind of extension installed that causes the problem.

Comment: @ad_on_is I see them in incognito too, but not in mozilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there is still no answer for this but I managed to figure it out. Those lines are appearing because you are seeing the color of the table through the "cracks". By matching the table's background-color attribute these lines go away.